# Tensorflow freezes when trying to create a session in docker container

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I'm trying to deploy a web site for the demo using CNN.
To serve this purpose, I built a docker image with dependencies (in my case tensorflow, keras and any other miscellanies).

I managed to built the docker image. However It fails when I tested on some sample images. I found out that the problem is tensorflow can not create a session. I still can import tensorflow and other packages. Even I can run a code for building computation graph with tensorflow code

```
(Ex,  
a=tf.constant(7)
b=tf.constant(10)
c = tf.add(a,b)
).
```

But it freezes whenever I try to create a tensorflow session `(Ex, sess = tf.Session()).`
Below is the code for building docker image.

```
def CNN_forward_example(self,image):

    a=tf.constant(7)
    b=tf.constant(10)
    c = tf.add(a,b)
    sess = tf.Session()
    print("I hope to see this message------------------------",c)
```

Expected result is to see the message "printed by print("I hope to see this message------------------------",c)".

Comment: Which OS is on the host machine? Please share your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue when I was using Docker. Can't find the link to the blog post but it basically recommends to set a global variable for the GRAPH.

```
GRAPH = tf.Graph()
# and then where you need it
with GRAPH.as_default():
    sess = tf.Session()
```

Here is a [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graphs) on how to use Graphs and Sessions. Here is a [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/docker) on TF serving with Docker.